# Shorewall multiple outgoing IPs allocation

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, firewall, shorewall

I have perfectly working VPN server with Shorewall installed. I got more IPs for the main eth0 interface so the server accepts the VPN connection from any of x.x.x.x/25 public IPs. But, the issue is that every connection (from any IP) gets one single main IP for outgoing traffic.

The question is how I can divide my tap interface (that VPN is using) and assign every 4 (for example) local IPs to a next public IP?

Here are the Shorewall masq lines I added but without success:

```
eth0:x.x.x.3        tap:192.168.30.12-192.168.30.15
eth0:x.x.x.4        tap:192.168.30.16-192.168.30.19
eth0:x.x.x.5        tap:192.168.30.20-192.168.30.23
```